# Philosophy and Mental Health

Tags: ethics, philosophy-of-mind, ontology, psychology

I have heard a story of a [Peace Pilgrim,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peace_Pilgrim) an American pilgrim and ascetic, who managed to heal one sick man through conversation. The man was suffering from general degeneration of health and doctors couldn't find the cure. Through the conversation with the sick man, Peace Pilgrim discovered how he was holding anger over his brother his whole life. She somehow managed to explain to the sick man why his father couldn't afford him college education and why his brother got it instead. At the end, the man released anger and his health suddenly improved. He got cured.

How can philosophies be used for healing people with mental issues? Can an ontic conversation bring about a proper perspective in the mind of a mental patient, which would naturally lead to emotional release and increase of well-being?

Comment: Mental health is a largely normative endeavor. The history of what constitutes "mental health" has been largely non-scientific and even is contentious in contemporary circles. See [Laing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R._D._Laing) and his antipsychiatry for examples of the struggles against soley using the medical model for diagnosis. Philosphically, remember that if one's representation does not match the objective world, one is bound to run into problems, and that conversation can help find inconsistencies in the gulf between one's thoughts and the state of affairs in the world...

Comment: Depression is often comorbid with other disorders, and is generally viewed as a psychosocoial maladjustment; language often exposes hidden presumptions and contradictions held by the "patient" which can be used to bring emotional issues to the fore, particularly in the non-mindful patient.